# Is () requested for invoking a Flex ActionScript constructor?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

In Flex ActionScript, a new object can be instantiated via the parameterless constructor with or without `()`. Example:

```
var array:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection()
```

or

```
var array:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection
```

Is there a difference between the two? Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: voted your question up... good point.  Of course if there are required args in your constructor -- AHBL.

Comment: Even if it's not required, please do add them for clarity :)

Comment: Is there a point to have convention to put 'new' in the constructor. If compiler can understand it is a constructor without '()' then it can understand without 'new' also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no difference functionally, but I like having the () just because of convention.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting point. Until your question I had never even tried passing a class to the "new" operator without a closure to indicate I was calling the constructor. I just tried it without and it works, but I wouldn't feel comfortable doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any differences between these two ways of instantiating an object, however convention would lean towards using `()`. Think about when you instantiate an object that requires parameters sent into the constructor `var e:Event = new Event('EventType');`, having the parentheses even when left empty tells you that nothing is getting passed in.

Answer (score -2):

if your not going to do anything with the constructor, then you don't even need to go that far:

```
var array:ArrayCollection;
```

would declare your variable just fine.

There is probably no real difference as the constructor is probably a magic method that will automagically be called when the class is called.

Comment: This just defines/declares the variable, it does not instantiate an instance of an ArrayCollection. Until instantiated the variable will be undefined.